# No Service on Galaxy SL GT I9003

Tags: mobile-network, samsung-galaxy-sl

I have a Samsung Galaxy SL running Android 2.3.6.

I bought a new battery and it was working perfectly until I put on recharge. Immidiately after I put it for recharge, it started showing "No Service". It does not receive any network coverage.

Everything else is working fine.

Comment: Did you try the Windows way (simple reboot // shutdown - remove battery - insert battery - restart)?

Comment: @Izzy certainly yes.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment due to limited experience.

- Where is your question?
- Try to insert the old battery and see if it improves the network coverage?
- A Izzy stated, try to turn it off, remove the battery and turn it on again.
- You can also try to turn on airplane mode for 1min, turn it off and check whether your network coverage gets back to normal. That's what I used when my 3G connection seems lost, it is faster than rebooting.
- Try with another (a friend's) SIM card,
- Change location where coverage might be better. The subway has no coverage, you know :-)